# Simple way to unify multiple date formats?

Tags: mysql, csv, datetime, timestamp

I need to import a large file of csv data into MySQL, and when I attempted to use MySQL's unix_timestamp function to import the dates, about half of the records didn't make it.

As far as I can tell, the datetime values are formatted with either a single first "month" digit or two of them, and the same goes with the day of the month (e.g. 6/6/2014 3:48PM vs. 12/16/2014 3:48PM) This throws off the import completely (well about half of the records won't import).

I'm trying to convert this into a unix_timestamp.

Now I know I could write a script with a regex to fix something like this, but I am wondering is there a simpler way to do a mass import like this? For the record, I am using my text editor to write the sql statements from the csv as "insert into" statements. This is where I tried to use date formatting but it seems to only accept one format.

Any way to do this with such a minor difference in input?

Comment: You're best bet would've been [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date); but even that requires you to specify date format used, so you'd still have to parse the string to find the format anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, despite my comment, something like this *might* work:

```
COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(val, "formatcandidate1")
   , STR_TO_DATE(val, "formatcandidate2")
   , STR_TO_DATE(val, "formatcandidate3")
   , STR_TO_DATE(val, "formatcandidate4")
   , [etc...]
   ) AS dateVal
```

Comment: No luck with this in MySQL 5.7 trying to deal with ISO date strings that might or might not have trailing millis: /* SQL Error (1411): Incorrect datetime value: '2018-06-14T20:08:12Z' for function str_to_date */

Answer (score 0):

There are online tools to do this kind of stuff
**reports.zoho.com** is one of them

In this tool you can import data applying a specific date format and skip the other rows.
and you can do the same for all the type of formats that are present in your file

and finally you can export the data with same date format for all the data

ask me any doubts if you have any regarding this :)